# C# ForEach Loop Tripling Results

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm returning the status code from 3 different URL's using a ForEach Loop to iterate through the results. It returns the results just fine, but is returning 3 sets of results.

```
public static List<Models.SiteStatus> GetStatus()
{
    statusList.Clear();

    // website urls to check
    string site1 = "https://www.google.com";
    string site2 = "https://www.google.com";
    string site3 = "https://www.google.com";

    int site1Status = 0;
    int site2Status = 0;
    int site3Status = 0;

    HttpStatusCode result = default;
    HttpWebResponse response = null;

    // add urls to a list to pass through
    List<Uri> urls = new List<Uri>();
    urls.Add(new Uri(site1));
    urls.Add(new Uri(site2));
    urls.Add(new Uri(site3));


    // check status per site
    foreach (Uri u in urls)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(u) as HttpWebRequest;
            // just request headers
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            result = response.StatusCode;
            // 15 second timeout
            request.Timeout = 15000;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                if (response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri == site1 && response.StatusCode == result)
                {
                    site1Status = (int)response.StatusCode;
                }
                if (response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri == site2 && response.StatusCode == result)
                {
                    site2Status = (int)response.StatusCode;
                }
                if (response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri == site3 && response.StatusCode == result)
                {
                    site3Status = (int)response.StatusCode;
                }

                var res = new SiteStatus
                {
                    url1Site = site1,
                    url1Status = site1Status,
                    url2Site = site2,
                    url2Status = site2Status,
                    url3Site = site3,
                    url3Status = site3Status
                };

                statusList.Add(res);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        // close connection
        response.Close();
    }
    return statusList;
}
```

The returned results appear something like this;

- Site 1 = 200
- Site 2 = 0
- Site 3 = 0

---

- Site 1 = 200
- Site 2 = 200
- Site 3 = 0

---

- Site 1 = 200
- Site 2 = 200
- Site 3 = 200

I just need the last set of results returned in the frontend html, but can't seem to figure it out. Any assistance it greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are creating a new set of results every time around the foreach loop.  Move the `new SiteStatus` lines outside of the loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move this line that creates `res` and add to the list out of the loop.

```
/// MOVE THIS HERE, JUST ABOVE 'RETURN'
var res = new SiteStatus
{
    url1Site = site1,
    url1Status = site1Status,
    url2Site = site2,
    url2Status = site2Status,
    url3Site = site3,
    url3Status = site3Status
};

statusList.Add(res);
///

return statusList;
```